# Write char array to specific memory-address

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, byte, memory-address

I have a huge byte array (char array) that I am using to write to another address.
e.g.

```
char myBytes[] = { 0x43, 0x31, 0x63 };//just an example
(char*)0x123456 = &myBytes;
```

but the problem is that I get an error saying

```
"expression must be a modifiable lvalue"
```

I've tried some other stuff like

```
char myBytes[] = { 0x43, 0x31, 0x63 };//just an example
*(char*)0x123456 = myBytes;
```

But I get the same error. What am i doing wrong and what can I do get what I want accomplished?

Comment: `memcpy((char*)0x123456, myBytes, sizeof(myBytes));` Bad idea, though...

Comment: `(char*)0x123456` is a constant of type `char *`.  You cannot assign to it any more than you can assign to the value `1`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., why are you so sure it is a bad idea?

Comment: @SergeyA Working with explicit addresses in C or C++ is justified in a very special cases only, while I am not quite sure it is the case for the OP. And even in these cases there are often other ways.

Comment: @EugeneSh., apparently, you never worked with MCUs, did you?

Comment: @SergeyA Apparently this is what I am working with everyday. But hardcoding memory addresses in this way is a bad idea still. If you want to  write a specific memory region - you define in in a linker script, and then place your variables there. If you want to write some HW registers, you *should* define them as `volatile` pointers somewhere. In *very rare* occasions you will hard-code the memory address as presented.

Comment: @EugeneSh., yes, you define them as volatile pointers, but this is just a level of indirection. In the end, you are writing to specific memory address.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `(char *)0x123456` is not a constant expression (constant expressions may not contain reinterpret_cast). It is a prvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign arrays with `=` in C++. The array name decays to a pointer when used like that, so you're trying to write the address of the array into the memory location. Use `memcpy()` to copy memory.

```
memcpy((void*)0x123456, (void*)mBytes, sizeof(mBytes));
```

Comment: Not only does the array *name* decay to a pointer, *any* array value decays to a pointer when evaluated.  Thus, you cannot even do tricks such as `*(char(*)[3]) myBytes` to get a handle on an array -- the array value resulting from that dereference just decays back to a pointer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the "decay" does not happen on every evaluation. It only happens when the context demands a decay  (which is most contexts, but not all). For example in `&myBytes` there is no decay, the address of the array results. And in your example (which is the same as `*&myBytes`), the `&` operator could be applied to the result.

Comment: @M.M, it is a fine point, to be sure, but evaluating the expression `&myBytes`, does not involve *evaluating* the array designated by `myBytes`, therefore that array does not decay to a pointer.  This (and my earlier comment) are consistent with what you've said.  I like this way of thinking about it because it has the advantage of requiring fewer exceptions, but it is admittedly a bit subtle.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  `&` evaluates its operand.  Every operand is evaluated unless the standard specifically says it is an *unevaluated operand*.  Which is true for `sizeof` but not for `&`.  Consider the code `&foo()` ; if `&` did not evaluate its operand then the function would not be called.

Comment: @M.M, good point, and I see that this is an area where C++ and C differ.  In C++, the result of evaluating a function call expression is an lvalue under some (but by no means all) circumstances.  As far as I can determine, the result of evaluating a C function call is never an lvalue.  When it is not an lvalue, the result of a function call expression is not an allowed operand for the `&` operator in either language.

Comment: @JohnBollinger C is no different, consider `&x[foo()]` for example.  The function is called

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you guys take your discussion elsewhere, like chat?

Comment: OK I'll stop posting